# How to make Jetty webserver listen on port 80?

Tags: webserver

I would like to use Jetty as a webserver.

I have edited the configuration file at `/etc/default/jetty` and set:

```
# change to 0 to allow Jetty start
NO_START=0

# Listen to connections from this network host
# Use 0.0.0.0 as host to accept all connections.
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Now I can reach the Jetty webserver at `http://192.168.1.10:8080` but I would like to have Jetty listening on port 80.

I have tried this setting in the same configuration file:

```
# The network port used by Jetty
JETTY_PORT=80
```

and then restart Jetty with `sudo service jetty restart` but it doesn't work.

How can I change so that the Jetty webserver is listening on port 80?

Comment: you can change it also from start.ini (jetty root), there you have --> jetty.port - line, uncomment and give it a value (default is 8080)

Comment: see also:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/68616692/4531180  for jetty 9.  but it's in in the `ini` file as described here for `jetty9`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to edit the `/etc/jetty/jetty.xml` file. Look for a paragraph that says:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" /></Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8090"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

Change the `jetty.port` Property to `80` as follows:

`<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="80"/></Set>`

Restart jetty. That should do it.

---

Since the above method did not work for OP, and running as root is discouraged, there is an alternative method, as mentioned in this [document](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80).

Comment: This doesn't work. I also checked with `sudo netstat -nlp` but Jetty is not listed.

Comment: It might be because jetty is not running as root. I am trying out a setting, and will post in a while.

Comment: I was able to get the default page by running `sudo java -jar start.jar` from `/usr/share/jetty`. I also configured the `/etc/jetty/jetty-setuid.xml` to start as privileged user.

Comment: Additionally take a look at: [running jetty as non root user](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80).

Comment: I run `sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080` and now it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: You want jetty to be the default webserver, and want all requests to be forwarded to `:80`? I once forwarded all queries to `:8090` which was jetty behind apache. Bad day for me. Glad it worked out for you :)

Comment: Yes, I have a small VPS and Jetty is the only thing I have installed so far, I want to serve some Servlets and JSP-files.

Comment: I'm glad you found iptables' redirect function before you reconfigured Jetty to run as root. That would have been a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Jetty 9. In the file start.ini you can find and modify the property `jetty.port`. Then you have to restart jetty.service.

Comment: It might be useful if you expand your answer by specifying the location of the start.ini file, the line in start.ini that has to be modified, and the modified text that has to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Neatest way to do it is with xinetd (you may need to install it on your server first) see here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Port80